# Get rich text from a shared point with Jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get the value from rich text box in javascript

Segue uma imagem Editar

Mas eu não encontrei seu id ou título
Segue uma imagem

But I did not find your id or title
Follows an image

I only have access to div.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `textContent` to get the text value of the element.

```js
var foo = document.getElementById('foo').textContent.trim();
console.log(foo);
```

```html
<div id="foo">
  <p>
    &apos;
    <span></span><span></span>
  </p>
</div>
```